# Converting JSON into XML Angular 7

Tags: javascript, json, angular, xml, angular7

EDIT: This doesn't work with the xml2js npm package since I want to do the opposite, convert json to xml, not the other way around.

I have my API using JSON data format but I also have to save the object that I updated in a text file in an XML format, since this other application that we communicate with only accepts XML format.

I have my service

shipment.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as x2js from 'xml2js';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShipmentService {
  baseUrl = "http://localhost:5000/api/shipments/"

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}


  getShipments() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
  }

  getShipment(id) {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + id);
  }

  updateShipment(id: number, shipment) {
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + id, shipment);
  }

}
```

And tracker.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ShipmentService } from 'src/app/services/shipment.service';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ShipmentModalComponent } from '../shipment-modal/shipment-modal.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgxSpinnerService} from 'ngx-spinner';

var convert = require('xml-js');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tracker',
  templateUrl: './tracker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tracker.component.css']
})
export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit {
  shipments:any = [];
  shipment:any = {};
  modal_on:boolean = false;
  modalcontent:any;
  closeResult = '';
  reference: string;

  constructor(
    private shipmentService: ShipmentService,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getShipments();
  }

  convertToXML(json) {
    var options = {compact: true};
    var result = convert.json2xml(json, options);
    console.log(result);
  }

  getShipments() {
    this.spinner.show(undefined,{
      type: "square-spin",
      size: "medium",
      bdColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
      color: "rgb(5, 5, 80)",
      fullScreen: false

    });
    this.shipmentService.getShipments().subscribe(response => {

      this.shipments = response;
      this.spinner.hide();

      this.convertToXML(response);

      console.log(response);
    }, error => {  
      console.log(error);
    });

  }

}
```

So I tried to use x2js and other xml2json libraries but I had no success converting the JSON object into an XML object or string for that matter.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]; what exactly does *"no success"* mean?

Comment: Where in your code you are doing the conversion?

Comment: I added the dependencies and the methods that request the object where I need to convert the json response into an xml object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install `npm i js2xmlparser`

```
import * as JsonToXML from "js2xmlparser";
console.log(JsonToXML.parse("person", this.obj));
```

Here `this.obj` is your JSON object

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-2-xml-example)

Comment: what if there are array of json objects? It will have person tag in the resulting xml file for every json object. How to restrict it to only one root tag/node?

Answer (score 1):

So I used js2xmlparser npm package and I wrote the following method on my service.ts file and component.ts file as follows:

service.ts

```
import * as JsonToXML from 'js2xmlparser';

convertXML(obj) {
    let options = {
      format: {
        doubleQuotes: true
      }, 
      declaration: {
        include: false
      }
    }

    return JsonToXML.parse("UniversalEvent", obj, options);
  }
```

and in my component.ts file i wrote the following method:

```
 openModal(content, shipment) {
    // this.modal_on = true;
    let new_obj = {};

    this.modalcontent = shipment;
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'});
    new_obj = this.addXmlAttr(new_obj);
    this.xmlShipment = this.shipmentService.convertXML(new_obj);


    console.log(this.xmlShipment)
    console.log(this.modalcontent);
  }

  addXmlAttr(obj) {
    obj = {
      "@": {
        xmlns: "http://www.cargowise.com/Schema/Universal/2011/11",
        version:"1.0"
      },
      Event: {
        DataContext: {
          DataTargetCollection: {
            DataTarget: {
              Type: "ForwardingShipment",
              Key: this.modalcontent.vortex_Reference
            }
          }
        },
        EventTime: this.modalcontent.actual_Pickup,
        EventType: "PCF",
        AdditionalFieldsToUpdateCollection: {
          AdditionalFieldsToUpdate: {
            Type: "ForwardingShipment.DocsAndCartage.JP_PickupCartageCompleted",
            Value: this.modalcontent.actual_Pickup
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return obj;
  }
```

As somebody suggested, I edited the json object to my specifications and then parsed it to XML and the converted object looks like so:

```
<UniversalEvent xmlns="http://exampleurl.com/Schema/Example/2011/11" version="1.0">
    <Event>
        <DataContext>
            <DataTargetCollection>
                <DataTarget>
                    <Type>ForwardingShipment</Type>
                    <Key>123456</Key>
                </DataTarget>
            </DataTargetCollection>
        </DataContext>
        <EventTime>2019-05-22T00:00:00</EventTime>
        <EventType>PCF</EventType>
        <AdditionalFieldsToUpdateCollection>
            <AdditionalFieldsToUpdate>
                <Type>ForwardingShipment.DocsAndCartage.JP_PickupCartageCompleted</Type>
                <Value>2019-05-22T00:00:00</Value>
            </AdditionalFieldsToUpdate>
        </AdditionalFieldsToUpdateCollection>
    </Event>
</UniversalEvent>
```